# How to revert end of line white-space changes using git?

Tags: git, diff, whitespace, git-diff, removing-whitespace

When applying patches on a legacy code-base that has a lot of trailing white-space, sometimes tools are configured to strip white-space *.

I would have hoped this would be as simple as:

```
git diff --ignore-space-at-eol > changes.diff
git stash
git apply changes.diff
```

...if all goes well drop the stash after.

Unfortunately I've tried this many times, often get this error when applying the patch:

```
patch does not apply
```

In some cases using `patch` without git works with some fuzz warnings.

Is there a robust way to revert white-space stripping?

---

* maybe we should bite the bullet and strip white-space, that's a discussion for another day :D

Comment: Try `git apply changes.diff --ignore-space-change` or `git apply changes.diff --ignore-whitespace`